# get a number of unique values without separating values that belong to the same block of values

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, ms-access, oracle11g

I'm OK with either a PL/SQL solution or an Access VBA/Excel VBA (though Access VBA is preferred over Excel VBA)  one. so, PL/SQL is the first choice, Access VBA is second and Excel VBA is third.

This is a very tough problem to explain. Please ask any questions and i will do my best to answer them clearly.

I have the following dataset in a table called NR_PVO_120. How do i pick out a number (which can change but let's say, 6) of UNIQUE OtherIDs without excluding any OtherIDs under any fax numbers?

So, if you pick OtherID from Row7 you then also must pick OtherIDs from rows 8 and 9 because they have the same fax number. Basically, once you pick an OtherID you're then obligated to pick all OtherIDs that have the same fax number as the one you picked.

If the number requested (6 for this example) isn't possible then "the closest number possible but not exceeding" would be the rule.

For example, if you take OtherIDs from rows 1-10 you will get 6 unique OtherIDs but row 10 shares a fax with rows 11 and 12. You either need to take all 3 (but that will raise the unique count to 8, which isn't acceptable) or skip this OtherID and find one with a fax that will add 1 unique OtherID (for example, it can have 4 OtherIDs but 3 of them exist on the result set and therefore don't add to unique counts). My result of 6 UNIQUE OtherIDs will need to contain ALL OtherIDs under any fax the existing OtherIDs are connected to.

So one solution is to take rows 1-6, 26. Another is to take rows 1-4,10-14. There are more but you get the idea.

There will be many possibilities (the real dataset has tens of thousands of rows and the number of people requested will be around 10K), as long all OtherIDs connected to all faxes on the result set are part of the requested number (6 in this case) any combination would do.

A few notes.

1. Getting as close as possible to the requested number is a requirement.
2. Some OtherIDs will have a blank fax, they should only be included as a last resort (not enough OtherIDs for the requested number).

How is this done?

```
Row      OtherID        Fax
1       11098554    2063504752
2       56200936    2080906666
3       11098554    7182160901
4       25138850    7182160901
5       56148974    7182232046
6       56530104    7182234134
7       25138850    7182234166
8       56148974    7182234166
9       11098554    7182234166
10      56597717    7182248132
11      56166294    7182248132
12      25138850    7182248132
13      56148974    7182390090
14      56226456    7182390090
15      56148974    7182395285
16      25138850    7182395285
17      56166614    7180930966
18      11098554    7180930966
19      56159509    7180930966
20      25138850    7185462234
21      56148974    7185462234
22      25138850    7185465013
23      56024315    7185465013
24      56115247    7185465281
25      25138850    7185465281
26      56148975    7185466029
```

A few sample outputs

one solution is taking rows 1-6 and 26.

```
Row      OtherID        Fax
1       11098554    2063504752
2       56200936    2080906666
3       11098554    7182160901
4       25138850    7182160901
5       56148974    7182232046
6       56530104    7182234134
26      56148975    7185466029
```

Another solution is taking rows 1-4 and 10-14.

```
Row      OtherID        Fax
1       11098554    2063504752
2       56200936    2080906666
3       11098554    7182160901
4       25138850    7182160901
10      56597717    7182248132
11      56166294    7182248132
12      25138850    7182248132
13      56148974    7182390090
14      56226456    7182390090
```

There are many more.

I only need FAX as my output.

This is for a fax campaign, we need to make sure no fax number is faxed twice, that all people connected to that fax number are contacted under one fax sent.

So the idea is to take all OtherIDs under ANY fax you end up using.

EDIT here's how it's currently done, maybe this helps paint a picture

list is sorted by fax, they go down the list to a random point MAKING SURE THE LAST RECORD ENDS WITH THE SAME FAX. so in my example they'd stop at either row 1,2,4,5,6,9,12,14,16,19,21,23,25,26. they then see how many unique OtherIDs they have up until that point. if it's too many they go up some, see how many they have. if it's too little, they go down some, see how many they have. and they keep doing this until they get their unique number. the only requirement is to always include all OtherIDs under a fax.

Comment: Please show what you want as expected output. 'breaking up fax numbers' does not help much.

Comment: Which specific Oracle version - 11g R1 (11.1) or 11g R2 (11.2) ?

Comment: As there can be many sets of data that answers the problem, what will be the preferred set of the multiple valid sets? A random set? Or is it OK if it is the set with the smallest or largest fax numbers? I guess a set with the smallest/largest numbers will mean that your fax campaign then would pick geographically clustered people, so you would probably need a somewhat random pick?

Comment: Hmmm... When I read your other two questions on this, I think you are desiring say 10K people out of your data for first run of your campaign, then you will pick 10K more for the second run, then 10K more for the third run, until you've contacted everybody? Would it be OK then with a query assigning every fax to a "bucket number" in one go rather than repeated calls? (That might be easier.)

Comment: And then you say you need to get as close as possible to the desired number of people. What if your data has 41 thousand people and you are asking for 10 thousand in each bucket? Do you need that it becomes 4 buckets with near 10 thousand people and then a fifth bucket with about 1 thousand people? Or is it OK if that becomes 5 buckets each with approximately 8.200 people?

Comment: Kim, 11.0.0.116. I only need the first 10K, the rest gets thrown away until they're ready to process another batch and then again, procedure will find the first 10K. for example, they want to do the state of CA but can only handle 10K. CA has 30K, so i pick the 10K and leave the rest until they ask for this state again. When they ask again, i get a new dataset based on rules we have and these 10K might show up again or might not, depending on when they ask, and again, the first random 10K will need to be chosen

Comment: the set can be random, it doesn't matter where they're located, how many people are tied to the fax. as long as every fax that makes it on the final list has ALL people under it - they're OK.

Comment: @Jim mcnamara. My desired output would be a unique list of OtherIDs that equals to or as close as possible to the number requested as long as every fax attached to these people has all the people under it. There can be many possibilities, i outlined them in the question. i will create a few sample outputs

Comment: @Kim Berg Hansen oops, i just realized you're not asking for my Oracle version, you're asking for the server db version. i'm not sure but can find out.

Comment: So lots of activity last week, but you were skyping with Dmitry last week. Is this still an active question or did you get what you needed from Dmitry? I think I understand what you're looking for: given the data in the examples, you want a method to send to the exact number of ID's specified, while using all ID's with a given fax num. The complicated part is that if an ID has multiple fax nums, only count that ID once. Am I correct that if an ID has 3 fax nums (for example) and using groups with 2 fax nums belonging to that ID meets the criteria, 3rd fax num does not need to be in the group?

Comment: Still active. I also posted on an MS Access site. Also asked people at work. No luck. I have an ugly solution in mind so if this doesn't get solved I can still get it done. As for your questions. You understand it correctly. You also understabd thr challenge correctly. If it wasn't for the unique requirement I'd have a solution already (Dmitry from an earlier question). The last part I'm not sure I understand. You mean if the fax number doesn't add any new OtherIDs then will it need to be on the results? If so then it doesn't matter

Comment: @lalachka In example, OtherID 11098554 is associated to 4 fax nums. Using rows 1-6 and 26 gets 2 of those 4, but not the other 2 (rows 9 and 18). So it does not matter if the OtherID gets 2 faxes on 1 day and 2 faxes on a different day (or days)? Also, for Access VBA, do you have a preference for using DAO or ADO?

Comment: no preference and that's OK, each fax is a different office, if he has 10 offices then he will get 10 faxes and that's OK, what they're trying to avoid is the same office getting 10 faxes. Dear OtherID1, Dear OtherID2, Dear OtherID3, etc. they'd like to do one fax per office like this, Dear OtherIDs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 2/13/2015
after using the accepted answer for a few months i came across a scenario that hasn't happened yet and realized that his solution only works if i need to get a number that's not too close to the total. for example, if my total number of records is 15000 and i'm asking for 12000 then his code will give 10 or 11k. if i ask for 8k then i will probably get the 8.

i don't understand what his code does and he never replied so i can't explain why this is happening, my guess is that he's taking the counts in a certain order and since the results are dependent on the order the faxes are sorted in - he won't necessarily get the best results every time. 
when there's enough room (asking 8l out of 15k) he has enough room for any combination to yield the acceptable result but once you ask for a tighter number (12k out of 15k) he's locked into his order and runs out of acceptable counts fast enough.

so this is the code that will give correct result no matter what. it's not nearly as elegant and is extremely slow but it works.

12/13/14 i think i got it, PL/SQL, not the best solution by far but it gives better results than what they currently get by hand. actually, would be really interested to hear about possible problems

12/13/14 EDIT the accepted answer is the way to do it, i'm only leaving this here for contrast, so people can see how not to code lol.

```
DECLARE
     CountsNeededTotal NUMBER;
     CountsNeededRemaining NUMBER;
     CurCountsTotal NUMBER;
     CurFaxCount NUMBER;
     CurFaxCountPicked NUMBER;
BEGIN
     CountsNeededTotal := 420;
     CurCountsTotal := 0;
     CurFaxCount := 0;

     CountsNeededRemaining := CountsNeededTotal - CurCountsTotal;

     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE NR_PVO_121';


     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --START BLOCK
     --this block jsut gets the first fax, the fax with the largest number of people
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################

     --get the first fax with the most people as long as thta number isn't larger than the number needed
     SELECT MAX(CountOfPeople) CountOfPeople
    INTO CurFaxCount
    FROM (SELECT     fax
            ,COUNT(1) CountOfPeople
           FROM NR_PVO_120
          GROUP BY Fax
         HAVING COUNT(1) <= CountsNeededRemaining);

     COMMIT;

     --if there is a number that's not larger then add to the table and keep looping
     --if there isn't then there's no providers from this campaign that can be used
     IF CurFaxCount >= 0 THEN
       --insert into the 121 table (final list of faxes)
       INSERT INTO NR_PVO_121
         SELECT   fax
              ,COUNT(1) CountOfPeople
             FROM NR_PVO_120
           HAVING COUNT(1) = (SELECT MAX(CountOfPeople) CountOfPeople
                       FROM (SELECT   fax
                               ,COUNT(1) CountOfPeople
                              FROM NR_PVO_120
                          GROUP BY Fax
                            HAVING COUNT(1) <= CountsNeededTotal))
         GROUP BY Fax;



       COMMIT;

       --############################################################################################
       --############################################################################################
       --############################################################################################
       --############################################################################################
       --############################################################################################
       --START BLOCK
       --this block loops through remaining faxes
       --############################################################################################
       --############################################################################################
       --############################################################################################
       --############################################################################################
       --############################################################################################



       SELECT SUM(CountOfPeople) INTO CurCountsTotal FROM NR_PVO_121;


       IF CurCountsTotal < CountsNeededTotal THEN
         CountsNeededRemaining := CountsNeededTotal - CurCountsTotal;


         --loop until counts needed remaining is 0 or as close as 0 as possible without going in the negative
         WHILE CountsNeededRemaining >= 0 LOOP
              --clear 122 table
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE NR_PVO_122';


              --loop through all faxes in 120 table  MINUS the ones in the 121 table
              DECLARE
                CURSOR CurRec  IS
                  SELECT DISTINCT Fax
                    FROM NR_PVO_120
                   WHERE Fax NOT IN (SELECT Fax FROM NR_PVO_121);
                PVO CurRec%ROWTYPE;
              BEGIN
                OPEN CurRec;
                LOOP
                  FETCH CurRec INTO PVO;

                  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(OtherID) CountOfPeople
                    INTO CurFaxCount
                    FROM NR_PVO_120
                   WHERE     Fax = PVO.fax
                      AND OtherID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT OtherID
                                   FROM NR_PVO_120
                                  WHERE fax IN (SELECT Fax FROM NR_PVO_121));
                  --                                                          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('CurFaxCount ' || CurFaxCount);
                  --                                                          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('CountsNeededRemaining ' || CountsNeededRemaining);

                  IF CurFaxCount <= CountsNeededRemaining THEN
                    --record their unique counts in 122 table IF THEY'RE NOT LARGER THAN CountsNeededRemaining
                    INSERT INTO NR_PVO_122
                         SELECT PVO.fax
                            ,CurFaxCount
                        FROM DUAL;

                    COMMIT;
                  END IF;
                  EXIT WHEN CurRec%NOTFOUND;
                --end fax loop
                END LOOP;
                CLOSE CurRec;
              END;


              --pick the highest count from 122 table
              SELECT MAX(CountOfPeople) CountOfPeople INTO CurFaxCountPicked FROM NR_PVO_122;

              --add this fax to the 121 table
              INSERT INTO NR_PVO_121
                SELECT MIN(Fax) Fax
                   ,CurFaxCountPicked
                  FROM NR_PVO_122
                 WHERE CountOfPeople = CurFaxCountPicked;


              COMMIT;
              --add the counts to the CurCountsTotal
              CurCountsTotal := CurCountsTotal + CurFaxCountPicked;
              --recalc   CountsNeededRemaining
              CountsNeededRemaining := CountsNeededTotal - CurCountsTotal;
              --
              --                                                          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('CurCountsTotal ' || CurCountsTotal);
              --                                                          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('CurFaxCountPicked ' || CurFaxCountPicked);
              --                                                          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('CurFaxCount ' || CurFaxCount);
              --                                                          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('CountsNeededRemaining ' || CountsNeededRemaining);
              --                                                          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('CountsNeededTotal ' || CountsNeededTotal);

              --clear 122 table
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE NR_PVO_122';
         --end while loop
         END LOOP;
       END IF;
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --END BLOCK
     --this block loops through remaining faxes
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################
     --############################################################################################



     END IF;
--############################################################################################
--############################################################################################
--############################################################################################
--############################################################################################
--############################################################################################
--END BLOCK
--this block jsut gets the first fax, the fax with the largest number of people
--############################################################################################
--############################################################################################
--############################################################################################
--############################################################################################
--############################################################################################



END;
```

here's a better version, MUCH faster than the above but it probably won't return perfect results in some cases. i wasn't able to get wrong results while testing but there is a possibility because i'm not trying every possible combination (as in the first version), that takes days to finish for a dataset of 20K records

```
DECLARE
    CountsNeededTotal NUMBER;
    CountsNeededRemaining NUMBER;
    CurCountsTotal NUMBER;
BEGIN
    CurCountsTotal := 0;

    SELECT NoOfProvToKeep INTO CountsNeededTotal FROM NR_PVO_121;

    CountsNeededRemaining := CountsNeededTotal - CurCountsTotal;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE nr_pvo_122';


    COMMIT;

    IF CurCountsTotal <= CountsNeededTotal THEN
        --loop until counts needed remaining is 0 or as close as 0 as possible without going in the negative
        WHILE CountsNeededRemaining > 0 LOOP
            --clear 122 table
            INSERT INTO NR_PVO_122
                SELECT Fax
                      ,CountOfPeople
                  FROM (SELECT   DISTINCT COUNT(OtherID) CountOfPeople
                               ,Fax
                       FROM NR_PVO_120
                      WHERE OtherID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT OtherID
                                    FROM NR_PVO_120
                                   WHERE fax IN (SELECT Fax FROM NR_PVO_122))
                     HAVING COUNT(1) <= CountsNeededRemaining
                        GROUP BY fax
                        ORDER BY 1 DESC)
                 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;



            SELECT SUM(CountOfPeople) INTO CurCountsTotal FROM NR_PVO_122;

            COMMIT;
            --recalc   CountsNeededRemaining
            CountsNeededRemaining := CountsNeededTotal - CurCountsTotal;
        --
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('CurCountsTotal ' || CurCountsTotal || ', CountsNeededRemaining ' || CountsNeededRemaining);
        --end while loop
        END LOOP;
    END IF;



    DELETE FROM NR_PVO_112
          WHERE NVL(Fax, '999999999999') NOT IN (SELECT Fax FROM NR_PVO_122);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but I don't want to write a lot of queries in comments.
Your main goal is to send information to people, and to avoid the situation when one person receives fax twice. So you first you need a list of unique recipients, like this:

```
select distinct otherid
  from NR_PVO_120
```

If one person has two fax numbers, you need to decide, which one to choose:

```
select otherid, fax
  from (select otherid, fax, row_number() over (partition by otherid order by <choosing rule>) rn
          from NR_PVO_120)
 where rn = 1
```

(All of this you have in answers of previous question)
If you take this list of fax numbers, all of your recipients receive the fax, and only one fax for every person. But some fax numbers will not be used. You can easily find them:

```
select otherid, fax
  from (select otherid, fax, row_number() over (partition by otherid order by <choosing rule>) rn
          from NR_PVO_120)
 where rn > 1
```

If you send fax to any of this numbers, some of people get one fax twice.
English is not my native language, so I don't understand what you mean when say "without breaking up fax numbers". As I can see in your question, possibly you need to use order of fax numbers in your question as number priority (the higher number is situated in the table - the higher probability to use it). It seems like you can use following:

```
select otherid, fax
  from (select otherid, fax, row_number() over (partition by otherid order by row) rn
          from NR_PVO_120)
 where rn = 1
```

here `row` in `order by` clause is a `Row` from your example table.

**UPD**
P. S. About my last query: we have a table with certain order, and the order is important. We take rows of the table line by line. Take first row and put its `otherid` and `fax` to result table. Then take next row. If it contains another `fax` number and `otherid`, we take it, if `otherid` already in our result table, we skip it. Did you ask this algorithm?

Comment: lol, as you can tell from my nickname, i also speak Russian and English isn't my native language either. However, i'm just not good at explaining things, in any language. "without breaking up fax numbers" means that if you picked a person that has the fax 4445555 and that fax number is also attached to 5 other people - those 5 people must make it on the campaign as well. Otherwise, this fax number will get a fax for one person in that office where it could've addressed all 6. and then at worst, another 5 faxes will be sent. I'm testing your queries now

Comment: nope, this isn't it. i will be at work in a few hours and will mess with your function. i have an idea, i think i need to add something in your loop that will check to make sure i have the right number of people and if not then keep looping. Your function works perfect. the only problem with it is that it gives me less people than i need because of the fact that one person has more than 1 fax. i know this is confusing, my head is spinning, it's been 4 days and nights or me messing with it

Comment: @lalachka If you want, you can try to explain me what you want in skype (see my profile). It will be much faster... Now it looks like discussion will never end.

Comment: @lalachka Check skype please

Answer (score 1):

This gets you most of the way there in standard SQL, it's not quite perfect and I expect that the [MODEL clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2172805) is what would work best, but...

What this does, is:

1. In `all_possible` work out every possible combination
2. In `some_counting` pivot this round and count the number of unique `otherid`s per `fax`. We can also restrict this to 6 here, so that we exclude any `fax`s which are never going to qualify
3. In `uniquify` use `row_number()` to ensure that we can split records that have the same number of `otherid`s per `fax` later and also work out the greatest. If this is 6 then you've got a simple win.
4. In `cumulative_sum` work out the running sum of the number of `otherid`s per fax. The trick here is the order in which you do it. I've chosen to pick the greatest first and then add in the smaller ones. I'm sure there's a cleverer way to do this... I did this because if the greatest is 6, you win. If it's 4, say, then you can fill it in with 2 `fax`s which only have 1 associated `otherid` etc.
5. Lastly restrict the cumulative sum to 6 records and pull in all the extra data you need.

Assuming a table as follows, filled with your data:

```
create table tmp_table ( 
   r number
 , otherid number
 , fax number
   );
```

the code would look like this:

```
with all_possible as (
select t.r as t_r, t.otherid as t_otherid, t.fax as t_fax
     , u.r as u_r, u.otherid as u_otherid, u.fax as u_fax
  from tmp_table t
  left outer join tmp_table u
    on t.fax = u.fax
   and t.r <> u.r
       )
, some_counting as (
 select fax 
      , count(distinct otherid) as no_o_per_fax
   from all_possible
unpivot ( (r, otherid, fax) 
        for (a, b, c)
         in ( (t_r, t_otherid, t_fax)
            , (u_r, u_otherid, u_fax)
            ))
 group by fax
having count(distinct otherid) < 6            
        )
, uniquify as (
select c.*
     , row_number() over (order by no_o_per_fax asc) as rn
     , max(no_o_per_fax) over () as m_fax
  from some_counting c
       )
, cumulative_sum as (
select u.*, sum(no_o_per_fax) over (order by case when no_o_per_fax = m_fax then 0 else 1 end
                                        , no_o_per_fax asc 
                                        , rn ) as csum
  from uniquify u
       )
, candidates as (
select a.*
  from cumulative_sum a
 where csum <= 6
       )
select b.*
  from tmp_table a
  join candidates b
    on a.fax = b.fax
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/244f4/1)

I make extensive use of common table expressions here to make the code look cleaner

Comment: i'm waiting to get access to our sql server so i can test it. i usually work in oracle or vba, not sql, but no problem, i'd use sql server if this works.

Comment: Your question is tagged Oracle, and it should work there. The UNPIVOT won't be identical in SQL Server... But, the rest should be the same, and the logic as well.

Comment: i'm confused, i thought you said this is an sql server solution, sorry lol, will try now.

Comment: got you, it works but not close enough. it gives me 5 where 6 couldve been possible. same with 12, gives 10 where 12 is possible.

Comment: lol i see, you said Standard sql as opposed to PL SQL? sorry, my brain is fried with this problem

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the requirements correctly, this should do it.

EDIT: I missed the uniqueness requirement. So, I've updated the code to account for that.

EDIT2: Added fax to the output, using a record type.

```
declare
    input_number int := 6;
    cursor get_faxes is
           select fax, count(*) num_ids from listofids
            group by fax
            order by fax;
    cursor get_ids (p_fax in int) is
           select otherid from listofids
             where fax = p_fax;
    type idrec is record(id listofids.otherid%type, fax listofids.fax%type);
    type idlist is table of idrec;
    output_list idlist := idlist();
    v_memberof  boolean;
begin
    for fax_rec in get_faxes loop
        if output_list.count + fax_rec.num_ids <= input_number then
            for id_rec in get_ids(fax_rec.fax) loop
                v_memberof := False;
                for i in 1..output_list.count loop
                    if output_list(i).id = id_rec.otherid then
                        v_memberof := true;
                    end if;
                end loop;
                if not v_memberof then
                    output_list.extend(1);
                    output_list(output_list.count).id := id_rec.otherid;
                    output_list(output_list.count).fax := fax_rec.fax;
                end if;
            end loop;
        end if;
    end loop;
    for i in 1..output_list.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line('id: ' || output_list(i).id || '  fax:' || output_list(i).fax);
    end loop;
end;
```

This now returns the following:

```
id: 11098554  fax:2063504752
id: 56200936  fax:2080906666
id: 56166614  fax:7180930966
id: 56159509  fax:7180930966
id: 25138850  fax:7182160901
id: 56148974  fax:7182232046
```

If you actually need a random selection, you can change the order by to use dbms_random.random instead of fax.

Comment: i only get 3 unique otherids, the results gives 6 but they're not unique

Comment: I missed that requirement. Sorry! I've updated the code. Let me know if that does it, or if I've missed something else.

Comment: no problem at all, thank you for even trying. can you give me fax numbers as the output? i'm getting the wrong results but i can't see why unless i know which faxes you picked. sorry :)

Comment: Edited to add faxes to the output. Hopefully that will help. Again, let me know what needs to happen next. This is turning into a fun problem.

Comment: sorry, just saw this, testing. it's fun for sure, i can't think about anything else for the past 10 days :)

Comment: wow, i think this is it and SOOOOOO much more elegant than mine, let me mess with it some more before i say for sure. EDIT i wish i checked here before i spent the day writing that atrocity i just posted. i gave up on getting an answer here lol

Comment: how did you do this???? i can't understand the code. the only solution i thought is possible is to loop through all possible combinations but your code runs lightening fast (mine takes 5 mins for the same set). can you please explain? this is amazing

Comment: hey, i'm getting a wrong results for one of my campaigns, it worked on tens of them so far, so not sure what's happening. i'm working on it but figured i'd post here in case you want to try as well

Comment: Sure, what's giving you grief?

Comment: i solved it already so this isn't pressing but i'd love to get your version to work, just for my education. can i send you my data set? it's about 20k records and i will tell you what number i'm trying to get. and then you will see what you're getting

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your requirement but this is the best I have understood your question.
First the code is sorting the data on Fax and then extracting the IDs where Fax is appearing for the the first time, even after that because of the data, there are duplicates IDs, so again sorting and removing duplicates is being done.

```
Sub Unique_fax()
```

Finding the last row so that loop can run that many times

```
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Copying the data to new rows so that your original data remains intact

```
For i = 1 To lastrow

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value = Trim(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1))
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value = Trim(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2))
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value = Trim(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3))

Next
```

Sorting the data based on Fax

```
Range("E1:G" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("G1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                   Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
```

Copying the IDs where the Fax is different to a new row

```
x = 1
For i = 1 To lastrow
If Cells(i, 7) <> Cells(i + 1, 7) Then
Cells(x, 9) = Cells(i, 6)
x = x + 1
End If
Next
```

Sorting the list of IDs and removing duplicates

```
lastrowUnq = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

Range("I1:I" & lastrowUnq).Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("I1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                   Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
y = 1
For j = 1 To lastrow
If Cells(j, 9) <> Cells(j + 1, 9) Then
Cells(y, 11) = Cells(j, 9)
y = y + 1
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Column - A,B,C is your original Data.
Column - E,F,G is the data sorted on Fax.
Column - I contains the list of IDs where Fax was unique.
Column - K contains the final list of IDs(as required).

[image]

Comment: first of all, thank you for even trying :) but i don't understand what the result is. what do you mean by the "fax was unique"? also, i'm ultimately looking for a specific number of unique OtherIDs (the number will always change) that include ALL OtherIDs connected to any fax that ends up on the final list.

Comment: So there are repeatitive "Fax"es for the same IDs, my program is extracting the last "Fax"(See Columns F and G) and corresponding ID to it, after that there are still duplicate IDs ( see column I) and then it is keeping unique IDs in the column K. Were you expecting different result from this?

Comment: In essence it is doing what you were expecting - i.e. "we need to make sure no fax number is faxed twice, that all people connected to that fax number are contacted under one fax sent".

Comment: No, I just couldn't understand what I'm validating. you probably misunderstood what I'm saying which is what happens every time I try to explain it :) sorry. So, you picked row19 and 18 (was picked before) but not 17 which means this person won't make it on the list, won't be included in the fax (dear row 18,17 and 19), won't be marked as 'faxed' and will make it on another list to be faxed again next time fax center requests this state. Do you see what I'm saying? Sorry, I don't know how to explain this

Answer (score 0):

Data Tested at Beginning.  Note OtherID is in Col A and Fax in Col B: [image: Before]
First we are going to find the number of Unique IDs you want  NOTE: YOU WILL NEED A NEW SHEET CALLED "Use Me".  We will need a custom function for this.  This function can be run as an cell formula with syntax `=UniqueItems(B2:D5)` but we are going to use it in our Sub:

```vb
Function UniqueItems(ArrayIn, Optional Count As Variant) As Variant
'   Accepts an array or range as input
'   If Count = True or is missing, the function returns the number of unique elements
'   If Count = False, the function returns a variant array of unique elements
    Dim Unique() As Variant ' array that holds the unique items
    Dim Element As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FoundMatch As Boolean
'   If 2nd argument is missing, assign default value
    If IsMissing(Count) Then Count = True
'   Counter for number of unique elements
    NumUnique = 0
'   Loop thru the input array
    For Each Element In ArrayIn
        FoundMatch = False
'       Has item been added yet?
        For i = 1 To NumUnique
            If Element = Unique(i) Then
                FoundMatch = True
                Exit For '(exit loop)
            End If
        Next i
AddItem:
'       If not in list, add the item to unique list
        If Not FoundMatch And Not IsEmpty(Element) Then
            NumUnique = NumUnique + 1
            ReDim Preserve Unique(NumUnique)
            Unique(NumUnique) = Element
        End If
    Next Element
'   Assign a value to the function
    If Count Then UniqueItems = NumUnique Else UniqueItems = Unique
End Function
```

Here is the sub you need to find your Unique IDs and copy them over to the sheet "Use Me"

```vb
Sub FaxesToUse()
    Dim LastRow As Long, CurRow As Long, UniqueTotal As Long, SubTotal As Long

    UniqueTotal = InputBox("How Many Unique OtherIDs is Max?")
    If Not UniqueTotal > 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    SubTotal = 0
    For CurRow = 2 To LastRow
        SubTotal = UniqueItems(Range("A2:A" & CurRow))
        If SubTotal > UniqueTotal Then
            SubTotal = UniqueItems(Range("A2:A" & CurRow - 1))
            Range("A1:B" & CurRow - 1).Copy
            Sheets("Use Me").Cells.Clear
            Sheets("Use Me").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Sheets("Use Me").Activate
            MsgBox "Use Me Sheet rows contain " & SubTotal & " Unique OtherIDs"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Cells(CurRow, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Next CurRow

End Sub
```

That will get you a page that looks like this: [image: After Faxes Runs] Now we just need to remove all the duplicate Faxes using this macro:

```vb
Sub RemoveDups()

Dim CurRow As Long, LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, DestLast As Long, DestRng As Range, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Use Me")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = LastRow To 3 Step -1
     Set DestRng = ws.Range("B2:B" & CurRow - 1).Find(ws.Range("B" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
     If DestRng Is Nothing Then
         'Do Nothing
     Else
        DestLast = ws.Cells(DestRng.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        ws.Cells(DestRng.Row, DestLast).Value = ws.Cells(CurRow, 1).Value
        ws.Cells(CurRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
     End If
     Next CurRow
ws.Columns("B:B").Cut
ws.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Application.CutCopyMode = False

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = 0
For CurRow = 2 To LastRow
    If ws.Cells(CurRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column > LastCol Then
        LastCol = ws.Cells(CurRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End If
Next CurRow

MsgBox "Use Me Sheet Rows contain " & UniqueItems(ws.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))) & " Unique OtherIDs"

End Sub
```

Leave you with this: [image: After Remove Dups]

Comment: I'm going to test now but since you're giving me unique ids that's all that matters, i will be taking thrm and mapping them back to my list and will get all faxes for those people. If this was done right then any people from any of his faxes will also be on the list so it all works out.

Comment: nope, i'm wrong, just spoke to the guy that does this by hand and there's a mistake in the process. you're right, it does matter which is picked. what they're doing is sorting by fax and going down the line. so they take a fax, take all OtherIDs, remove dups from OtherIDs, count, not enough, next, emove dups from OtherIDs, count, not enough, take all OtherIDs, next... so to them this qestion doesn't exist because they start with fax numbers and then pick all people from them.

Comment: So my process works, you just need to ID removed if it has already been faxed (earlier in the process)?

Comment: about to test now, sorry, was trying to get clarification from my job.

Comment: ok, i see what it does. it's the other way around though (which is fine, i just switched columns), i need to get all otherids under a fax, i don't care if he's somewhere else with a diff fax. but I already have a query that does this (from a pevious question, not sure if i shouldve posted it), the real problem is getting a certain unique number of OtherIDs because there's no good way of knowing how many unique OtherIDs the next fax number will bring.

Comment: @lalachka My code as posted takes all IDs assigned to one fax and combines them on one row.  See my screenshots here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360649/error-handling-with-range-find-vba (Data Before: and Data with my full code: screengrabs show what my code does)

Comment: ok, maybe i had my columns in the wrong order, in any case, i reordered them and got the same result as you. problem is getting a number or unique OtherIDs from that list. lets say i need 6 unique otherids while keeping all otherids from the same fax. how would you do it?

Comment: So basically if you had two faxes with the same OtherID associated, you would want to drop the OtherID from the second fax number line (using my output as an example) and still send the fax to the rest of the OtherIDs on that line associate with that fax?

Comment: not necessarily. you may end up also pickinig that second fax number, that's not prohibited. i need to get a unique number of people, they can be related to any faxes. BUT if you pick a fax - you're obligated to take the rest of the people under that fax. for example, you take the first fax, 5 people are attached, they all must go on the list. pick the next fax, 3 people are attached, they all must go on the list. it doesn't matter whether they're connected to any other faxes. cont...

Comment: the challenge is knowing how to get a unique number of people since the number of unique people attached to any fax will changed depending on which fax numbers are currently picked.

Comment: So
>> Fax A has OtherID 1, 2, and 3
>> Fax B has OtherID 3, 4, and 5
If you select A, then it sends to 1, 2, and 3 and B would drop 3 and just send to 4 and 5?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66418/discussion-between-lalachka-and-chrismas007).

Comment: ignore, didn't realize the fist block ispart of the answer, thought it was the old answer. testing

Comment: @lalachka My code is tested working.  I have now included images of my test data (using your test data from your original post) and what my data looks like after each step of the process.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if I'm wrong. I will try with your set of data and then mine

Comment: it's still running (my dataset is large) but i think i know what happened. i had autoids, i thought i was supposed to leave them them in. so let's see what happens.

Comment: omg i think it works!!!!! i can't believe it. 2 things but if it can't be easily done then it's ok, i will mess with it myself. first, is there any way to also show the fax that was picked? that wasn't the original requirement, yesterday it turned out they h ave a mistake and they need IDs AND faxes in the result. and second, is there any way to have the results in 2 columns as opposed to many rows?

Comment: All the faxes that are picked should be highlighted.  What do you mean by "results in columns"?  Could you post in your original question a screenshot with an example?

Comment: you're right, i have faxes, i forgot that i copied results to the second sheet to mess with it and count the IDs. sorry, i'm not usually this brainless. never mind second question, i can esily do it myself. thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: hey, sorry, i know what happened. i combined your subs without realizing that the sub is being exited at some point. i kept getting really weird results. so one last time, thank you and sorry for not realizing it sooner

Comment: i sent you a chat message. sorry, it doesn't work. it works on smaller numbers, like 8, or 17, but once you go up you end up with less OtherIDs than asked while the program says it found almost as many as needed. another problem, if i ask for 57, it tells me it found 56. 57 is definitely possible, so that's a problem. and it then gives 55.

Comment: @lalachka This will now check for your UniqueIDs FIRST until it has enough lines to proceed.  It will copy those lines over to a new sheet called "Use Me".  Then run `RemoveDups()` and it will get all the IDs on one line with the Fax associated.  TESTED WORKING

Comment: Lol nope. Still same problem