# Error Handling with Range.Find() VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292792/get-a-number-of-unique-values-without-separating-values-that-belong-to-the-same/27360529#27360529) with this WORKING code:

This vba code will loop through all IDs from the bottom up, if the fax number already exists, it will ADD the ID to that line in columns C, D, E, etc (always choosing the next blank) and then delete the line.  At the end it swaps columns A and B so you are left with a fax number in Col A and Cols B, C, D, E, etc are ALL IDs associated with that number.

Tested Working:

```
Sub RemoveDups()

Dim CurRow As Long, LastRow As Long, DestLast As Long, DestRng As Range

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next
 For CurRow = LastRow To 3 Step -1
     Set DestRng = Range("B2:B" & CurRow - 1).Find(Range("B" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        DestRng = DestRng
     If Err > 0 Then
        Err.Clear
     Else
        DestLast = Cells(DestRng.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Cells(DestRng.Row, DestLast).Value = Cells(CurRow, 1).Value
        Cells(CurRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
     End If
 Next CurRow
Columns("B:B").Cut
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Application.CutCopyMode = False

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

**My question is this:**  Why do I need the extra line `DestRng = DestRng`?  The reason I added it is because the code was non-functioning, so I added a check to dump `DestRng` into a `Cells.Value`.  All the sudden, the code worked, so I made a simple `DestRng = DestRng` line to ensure there was still code that could error.  If I comment out that line, it goes back to non-functioning code. Trying to figure out the reason why the `Range.Find()` will not activate the Error handler, but the `DestRng = DestRng` will activate the Error handler.

EDIT: Screenshots:

- Data Before:
  [image: DataBefore]
- Data with `DestRng = DestRng` AND `EntireRow.Delete` commented out: [image: CommentOut]
- Data with my full code: [image: FullCode]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Removing the `DestRng = DestRng` doesn't change the behavior as far as I can tell. It is functional either way. What is the simplest set of data in the spreadsheet with which you can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Added screengrabs @JackieChiles

Comment: `Find` doesn't error if the search value isn't found, it returns `Nothing` which is what you should test: `If Not DestRng Is Nothing Then`

Comment: @Rory My problem was more using some old code with a variable type that couldn't use `Nothing` so it triggered the error on the definition line.

Comment: @Chrismas007 I'm confused. You can't assign the result of a `Find` to a variable type that can't be set to `Nothing`.

Comment: @Rory see my comment below to Gary's... I was using a similar error handling for creating a new sheet.  And when you look for the sheet already exists, it triggers and error.  I was using the same logic thinking that the `Find` returning `Nothing` would error on being set to the `Range` variable.  But your suggestion is the more valid way to simplify the code.  While it doesn't answer the question of why I need the extra line like Gary's answer, I would upvote your answer if you added as it is a better way to write the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start with a completely empty worksheet and run:

```
Sub errorTest()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Cells.Find(what:="something", after:=Range("A1"))
    r = r
End Sub
```

The code will fail on the

```
r=r
```

line.  That is because the **Set** command sets r to *Nothing* and

```
r=r
```

is equivalent to:

```
r.Value=r.Value
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using code from creating a new sheet if one doesn't exist and in that case you can't set `createNewSheet = Nothing` as it Errors.  Glad to know why that works then.

Comment: Please mention that `Range` defaults to `.value` because it is the default member property of `Range`.  This behavior occurs with all objects that have a default member property.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate for me to use `DestRng.Value = DestRng.Value` to trigger the error in case the default doesn't trigger?  Otherwise I could just rewrite it as `If Not Nothing Then do stuff Else Next`