# Excel Create Text Files From Row Data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with Record IDs in Column A and text values in Column B. I need to create a text file for each unique Record ID that contains the matching text in Column B. There are 362 unique Record IDs in column A and 1,825 total records.

I searched Stack Overflow and found the link below which works for creating a separate text file for each unique Record ID. But, this is overwriting the text file with all duplicate values (only the last Record ID and text are saved, not all of the text values that match each Record ID). How can I edit this script so that if the text file exists, it is updated instead of overwritten?

[Create text Files from every row in an Excel spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077740/create-text-files-from-every-row-in-an-excel-spreadsheet)

Comment: I have some code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27360529/4241535 that will delete your duplicates and create one line with each entry after the Record ID.  (Will need slight modification to your purpose).

Answer (score 0):

*Just an example using `CreateTextFile` method*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim TextFile As Object
    Set TextFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("D:\example.txt", True)
        TextFile.WriteLine ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text
        TextFile.Close
End Sub
```