# Convert from list to flat CSV with modified data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have lists of Irish/Scottish clan names that I need to put into a format for my search module to use. Here is the problem:

```
O'Quinn     Antrim
Quillan     Antrim
Quin        Antrim
Quinn       Antrim
Alinden     Armagh
Baron       Armagh
Barron      Armagh
Branagan    Armagh
Calan       Armagh
```

I have lists of names (100k+ in 15 files that have 2-10k lines) that I would like to convert to a style that is workable. I would like to see them like this:

```
Antrim:O'Quinn, Quillan, Quin, Quinn, 
Armagh:Alinden, Baron, Barron, Branagan, Calan
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this achieved without a lot of manual intervention?

Comment: This is going to require some kind of scripting. Personally, I would write a script in node.js to process the files. I don't know of a way to do this in Excel directly.

Comment: I tried to use the =subsutite and tried to use and I also tried to do "A1","A2","A3" in a single row. The problem is there are so many, I was hoping there was an easier way to get this resolved without having to do a lot of this by hand, since there are so many. I do not know scripting for excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used something like this in another answer: (Edit: Fixed some small errors and updated syntax)  Tested Working!

Before Code:
[image]

```vb
Sub RemoveDups()

Dim CurRow As Long, LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, DestLast As Long, DestRng As Range, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = LastRow To 3 Step -1
     Set DestRng = ws.Range("B1:B" & CurRow - 1).Find(ws.Range("B" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
     If DestRng Is Nothing Then
         'Do Nothing
     Else
        DestLast = ws.Cells(DestRng.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        ws.Cells(DestRng.Row, DestLast).Value = ws.Cells(CurRow, 1).Value
        ws.Cells(CurRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
     End If
     Next CurRow
ws.Columns("B:B").Cut
ws.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

After Code:
 [image]

Comment: Well the other Q was looking for a different solution ([finding unique values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292792/get-a-number-of-unique-values-without-separating-values-that-belong-to-the-same)) which I partially solved with the above VBA.

Comment: Meaning the O.P. is plagiarizing or I am plagiarizing?  Can you plagiarize yourself? :-D

Comment: Works like a champ!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In three parts, assuming `O'Quinn` is in A2:

> **Create the strings**

In C2:

```
=IF(B1<>B2,B2&": "&A2,C1&", "&A2)
```

> **Identify those relevant**

In D2:

```
=B2<>B3
```

> **Tidy up**

Copy C2:D2 down to suit.
Select Sheet, Copy, Paste Special Values.
Filter ColumnD to select `FALSE` and delete all visible and Columns D and A.
Repeat for other 14 files.

Comment: Plus one for the non-code solution. Often overlooked when it comes to Excel.

Comment: Yes. I meant here. The knee jerk reaction of any programmer is to bust out the IDE after all...